# How to test a custom scheduler with celerybeat?

Tags: python, couchbase, celerybeat

I'm writing in python a custom scheduler class for celerybeat based on the [celerybeat-mongo](https://github.com/zakird/celerybeat-mongo) project which works with mongodb.

Actually I'm trying to make this work with couchbase instead of mongodb.
I wrote a ScheduleEntry class and a Scheduler class as well, I get the schedulers list from a couchbase document and parse it into ScheduleEntry objects, etc...

But when I run it as told in this [link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes), nothing seems to happen

```
celery -A <my.task.file> beat -S <my.scheduler.CouchBaseScheduler>
```

I'm pretty new to celery, I already ran some workers with tasks but I don't know quite exactly how the scheduler works. Celerybeat is starting well, I only know that it reads my schedulers correctly from the database but then no task seems to be called despite the fact I indicated the tasks in my tasks.py file.

Am I in the right direction? Is the command line above ok? How could I debug it since my only way to run it is from the command line (using subprocess to start it from a script and debug it would be dirty).

Edit: I add some details about this:

First of all I wrote a basic task in a tasks.py file:

```
import celery
import os
from datetime import datetime
from celery.utils.log import get_logger

def log_task_info(task_name, process_index, init_date):
    # logger.warn(task_name + ': ' + str(process_index) + ':' + str(init_date) + ' : ' + str(os.getpid()) + ':' +
    #             str(datetime.now()))
    get_logger(__name__).warning(task_name + ': ' + str(process_index) +
                                 ':' + str(init_date) + ' : ' + str(os.getpid()) + ':' + str(datetime.now()))

@celery.task(name='tasks.heartbeat')
def heartbeat():
    log_task_info('heartbeat', os.getpid(), datetime.now())
    return "Hello!"
```

Then I subclassed the Scheduler and SchedulerEntry classes.

```
class CouchBaseScheduler(Scheduler):

    UPDATE_INTERVAL = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)

    Entry = CouchBaseScheduleEntry

    host = "192.168.59.103"
    port = "8091"
    bucket = "celery"
    doc_string = "scheduler_list"
    password = "1234"
    scheduleCount = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(current_app.conf, "CELERY_COUCHBASE_SCHEDULER_BUCKET"):
            bucket_str = current_app.conf.CELERY_COUCHBASE_SCHEDULER_BUCKET
        else:
            bucket_str = "celery"
        if hasattr(current_app.conf, "CELERY_COUCHBASE_SCHEDULER_URL"):
            cnx_string = "{}/{}".format(current_app.conf.CELERY_COUCHBASE_SCHEDULER_URL, bucket_str)
        else:
            cnx_string = "couchbase://{}:{}/{}".format(self.host, self.port, self.bucket)

        try:
            self.bucket = Bucket(cnx_string, password=self.password, quiet=True)
            self.couchcel = CouchBaseCelery(self.bucket, self.doc_string)
            get_logger(__name__).info("backend scheduler using %s", cnx_string)
            self._schedule = {}
            self._last_updated = None
            Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.max_interval = (kwargs.get('max_interval')
                             or self.app.conf.CELERYBEAT_MAX_LOOP_INTERVAL or 5)
        except AuthError:
            get_logger(__name__).error("Couchbase connection %s failed : Auth failed!", cnx_string)
        except CouchbaseError as cbe:
            get_logger(__name__).debug("Couchbase connection %s failed : %s", cnx_string, type(cbe))


    def setup_schedule(self):
        pass

    def requires_update(self):
        if not self._last_updated:
            return True
        return self._last_updated + self.UPDATE_INTERVAL < datetime.datetime.now()

    def get_from_database(self):
        self.sync()
        try:
            get_logger(__name__).info("Getting scheduler list from couchbase.")
            couch_scheduler_list = self.couchcel.get_scheduler_list()
            return couch_scheduler_list
        except Exception as e:
            get_logger(__name__).error("Could not get scheduler list from couchbase: {}".format(e))

    @property
    def schedule(self):
        # self.scheduleCount += 1
        # get_logger(__name__).info("Scheduling {}".format(self.scheduleCount))
        if self.requires_update():
            get_logger(__name__).info("Schedule {} requires update".format(self.scheduleCount))
            self._schedule = self.get_from_database()
            self._last_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
        return self.schedule

    def sync(self):
        for entry in self._schedule.values():
            entry.save(self.couchcel)
```

and

```
class CouchBaseScheduleEntry(ScheduleEntry):

    def __init__(self, taskid, task):
        self._task = task

        self.app = current_app._get_current_object()
        self._id = taskid
        get_logger(__name__).info("Task id: {} processing".format(self._id))
        try:
            if all(k in self._task for k in ('name', 'task', 'enabled')):
                self.name = self._task['name']
                self.task = self._task['task']
            else:
                raise Exception("Field name, task or enabled are mandatory!")

            self.args = self._task['args']
            self.kwargs = self._task['kwargs']
            self.options = self._task['options']

            if 'interval' in self._task and 'crontab' in self._task:
                raise Exception("Cannot define both interval and crontab schedule")
            if 'interval' in self._task:
                interval = self._task['interval']
                if interval['period'] in PERIODS:
                    self.schedule = self._interval_schedule(interval['period'], interval['every'])
                    get_logger(__name__).info("Task contains interval")
                else:
                    raise Exception("The value of an interval must be {}".format(PERIODS))
            elif 'crontab' in self._task:
                crontab = self._task['crontab']
                self.schedule = self._crontab_schedule(crontab)
                get_logger(__name__).info("Task contains crontab")
            else:
                raise Exception("You must define interval or crontab schedule")

            if self._task['total_run_count'] is None:
                self._task['total_run_count'] = 0
            self.total_run_count = self._task['total_run_count']
            get_logger(__name__).info("Task total run count: {}".format(self.total_run_count))

            if not self._task['last_run_at']:
                self._task['last_run_at'] = self._default_now()
            else:
                self._task['last_run_at'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(self._task['last_run_at'], DATEFORMAT)
            self.last_run_at = self._task['last_run_at']
            get_logger(__name__).info("Task last run at: {}".format(self.last_run_at))
        except KeyError as ke:
            print('Key not valid: {}'.format(ke))

    def _default_now(self):
        return self.app.now()

    def next(self):
        self._task['last_run_at'] = self.app.now()
        self._task['total_run_count'] += 1
        self._task['run_immediately'] = False
        get_logger(__name__).info("NEXT!")
        return self.__class__(self._task)

    __next__ = next

    def is_due(self):
        if not self._task['enabled']:
            return False, 5.0 # 5 secs delay for reenable
        if self._task['run_immediately']:
            # figure out when the schedule would run next anyway
            _, n = self.schedule.is_due(self.last_run_at)
            return True, n
        return self.schedule.is_due(self.last_run_at)

    def _crontab_schedule(self, crontab):
        return celery.schedules.schedule(minute=crontab['minute'],
                                         hour=crontab['hour'],
                                         day_of_week=crontab['day_of_week'],
                                         day_of_month=crontab['day_of_month'],
                                         month_of_year=crontab['month_of_year'])

    def _interval_schedule(self, period, every):
        return celery.schedules.schedule(datetime.timedelta(**{period: every}))


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<CouchBaseScheduleEntry ({0} {1}(*{2}, **{3}) {{4}})>'.format(
            self.name, self.task, self.args,
            self.kwargs, self.schedule
        )

    def reserve(self, entry):
        new_entry = Scheduler.reserve(self, entry)
        return new_entry

    @property
    def getid(self):
        return self._id

    @property
    def gettaskdict(self):
        return self._task

    def tojson(self):
        return json.dumps(self.tocouchdict())

    def save(self, couchcel):
        get_logger(__name__).info("Saving task {} in couchbase".format(self._id))
        if self.total_run_count > self._task['total_run_count']:
            self._task['total_run_count'] = self.total_run_count
        get_logger(__name__).error("{}, {}".format(self.last_run_at, self._task['last_run_at']))
        try:
            if self.last_run_at and self._task['last_run_at'] \
                    and self.last_run_at > self._task['last_run_at']:
                self._task['last_run_at'] = self.last_run_at

        except TypeError:
            if self.last_run_at and self._task['last_run_at'] \
                    and self.last_run_at > datetime.datetime.strptime(self._task['last_run_at'], DATEFORMAT):
                self._task['last_run_at'] = self.last_run_at
        self._task['run_immediately']= False
        couchcel.save_scheduler(self)
```

The couchcel object is used for database access, the ScheduleEntry object parses the datas coming from the couchbase document.

Best regards

Comment: Not familiar with celery-beat. However, celery workers emit a log to /var/log/celery. Tried looking there? Raising the log-level?

Comment: I work under OSX, checked in the root folder for logs but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the [Celery website](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) seems to be a bit misleading. If you look [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/bin/worker.py), you can see that the command line option `-S` sets the state database, not the scheduler for the worker.

Try running this with the `--scheduler` option instead:

```
celery -A <my.task.file> beat --scheduler <my.scheduler.CouchBaseScheduler>
```